# I have installed pytz via pip but "import pytz" throws a module not found exception

Tags: python, pytz

I installed pytz on Debian Buster via

```
sudo pip install pytz
```

and the install completed cleanly.  However, when I attempt to

```
import pytz
```

python throws an exception

```
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

I installed pytz 2019.3 via pip 18.1.   Any thoughts on why pytz is not found?

Update:  I ran `pip -v` and now see that it is using python2.7.  Is there a way to tell pip to use python3?  I cannot remove python2 as it is a dependency for a number of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pip3` to install modules for `python3`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @emrah-diril answer:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

and then use

```
sudo pip3 install pytz
```